# css clearfix affected by siblings

Tags: html, css, clearfix

I define a container element contains a float div and a ul,
and the ul element contains a few float li element.
I want to clear the ul's float ,but the ul's height affected by its float sibling element.
Is it a bug the clearfix has?

```
 .clearfix {
    *zoom: 1; 
 }
 .clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    line-height: 0;
    clear:both; 
    visibility: hidden; 
 }
```

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/ltchronus/MV9pm/ to see my demo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MV9pm/10/ try

Comment: @AlexWilson I want subcontainer act auto to its content.Just like this  http://jsfiddle.net/ltchronus/MV9pm/13/.I don't konw why chearfix can't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug isn't in the clearfix, the "bug" *is* the clearfix.

Because the `div` is floating, the clearfix has to clear that floating sibling even though it's not part of the contents of the `ul` in the source. This is because both the `ul`'s floating contents and the floating `div` participate in the same [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (that of the root element).

You can easily correct this by triggering a new block formatting context in the `ul` by setting its `overflow` property to something other than `visible` to ensure that the clearfix is localized to just the `ul`'s formatting context, but then once you do that the clearfix becomes completely unnecessary anyway and you may as well get rid of it altogether.

This is why I personally do not use, and do not recommend using, clearfix: at best it's an unnecessary hack — which is not to say setting `overflow` *isn't* a hack; it is, too, since triggering BFCs is but a [not-so-intended side-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515) and certainly not what `overflow` was designed to do, but it's far easier to troubleshoot than issues caused by clearfix like the one you just ran into, especially if you do not have a solid understanding of the float model (and [even *I* don't claim that myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196773/why-is-this-non-float-margin-collapsing-with-a-float))

Comment: I think you're right. I don't understand the BFC and float model totally.

Comment: @luting: You don't have to, in that case. All you need to know is that the clearfix is affecting the sibling because that's just how floats work.

Comment: where can i find the detail of BFC?

Comment: @luting: There's a great in-depth introduction on this very site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196725/how-does-the-css-block-formatting-context-work Just keep in mind that it's a complicated topic which can take a bit of effort to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MV9pm/10/)

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="side-bar"></div>
    <ul class="sub-container clearfix" >
      <li>afjapfjapgj</li>
      <li>afjapfjapgj</li>        
      <li>afjapfjapgj</li>
      <li>afjapfjapgj</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
```