# How to absolute position with border width counted in

Tags: css, css-position

I have some trouble with absolute position.

```
<div class="frame" style="position:relative; width:100px;height:100%; box-sizing:border-box; border:10px solid black;">
    <div class="problem" style="width:20px; height:100%; position:absolute; right:-20px;"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the ".problem" is using the right boundary of ".frame" without considering border width, so basically it is inside the frame a 20px; I wonder how can let the ".problem" use the boundary of border as right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to position an element relative to the border-box of its parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367174/is-it-possible-to-position-an-element-relative-to-the-border-box-of-its-parent)

Answer (score 0):

You've a typo  `posiiton:absolute` should be `position:absolute`

I've also added a solution to this question :[Is it possible to position an element relative to the border-box of its parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367174/is-it-possible-to-position-an-element-relative-to-the-border-box-of-its-parent)

Just in case, that helps!